# How to alter data constraint in duckdb R

Tags: sql, r, duckdb

I am trying to alter a Not Null constraint to a Null constraint in duckdb (R api) and can't get it to stick.  Here is an example of the problem.

```
drv<- duckdb()
con<- dbConnect(drv)
dbExecute(con, "CREATE TABLE db(a varchar(1) NOT NULL, b varchar(1) NOT NULL)")

d<- data.table(a = 1:3, b=c("a", NA, "b"))

#test 'not null' constraint
dbWriteTable(con, name = "db", value = d, append = T)
Error: Constraint Error: NOT NULL constraint failed: db.b
```

So here I try and alter 'db' to allow me to write 'd' with its NA value in column b

```
> dbSendQuery(con, "ALTER TABLE db ALTER COLUMN b SET DEFAULT NULL")
<duckdb_result 46970 connection=b6ff0 statement='ALTER TABLE db ALTER COLUMN b SET DEFAULT NULL'>

> dbWriteTable(con, name = "db", value = d, append = T)
Error: Constraint Error: NOT NULL constraint failed: db.b
```

It appears the 'dbSendQuery' to alter the table worked (no error at least), but its clear that the constraint was not changed.  Any ideas on how to make the constraint change stick?

Comment: I don't think duckdb's `ALTER TABLE` supports NOT NULL. A workaround is: 1. Create a new table with the NOT NULL constraint, 2. Ensure the first table doesn't have NULLs in the relevant column(s), 3. Copy the data from the first to second table, and then delete the first table.

Comment: @stevec not quite ... it's that `alter table` needs to drop the constraint of `not null`, so it's just a little different syntax

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `DROP NOT NULL` instead of `SET NOT NULL`.

```r
d <- data.table(a = 1:3, b=c("a", NA, "b"))DBI::dbWriteTable(duck, name = "db", value = d, append = T)
duck <- DBI::dbConnect(duckdb::duckdb())
DBI::dbWriteTable(duck, name = "db", value = d, append = T)
# ERROR [2023-05-13 14:11:15] {"msg":"uncaught error","error":"rapi_execute: Failed to run query\nError: Constraint Error: NOT NULL constraint failed: db.b","where":["DBI::dbWriteTable(duck, name = \"","DBI::dbWriteTable(duck, name = \"",".local(conn, name, value, ...)"],"pid":"511449"}
# Error: rapi_execute: Failed to run query
# Error: Constraint Error: NOT NULL constraint failed: db.b
```

Fixed:

```r
DBI::dbExecute(duck, "ALTER TABLE db ALTER COLUMN b DROP NOT NULL")
# [1] 0
DBI::dbWriteTable(duck, name = "db", value = d, append = T)
DBI::dbGetQuery(duck, "select * from db")
#   a    b
# 1 1    a
# 2 2 <NA>
# 3 3    b
```